# How is IP address 127.0.0.1 used in terms of servers?

Tags: ip, ip-address

I'm working on a project which enables a web-based server which is accessible through 127.0.0.1:8081.

But I am not really able to understand the concept of the ip address. Does it mean the address is only available from the device which opens up the server, or across the whole LAN on any computer connected to that same router?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is the standard used for `localhost`.  It always points back to the local machine.  To access that host from a different machine you'll need to use a routable IP address, whatever the host's IP is on that network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

127.0.0.1 is a special IP address that refers to your local machine. Localhost resolves to this address. If you want to make your server accessible from the web or a different machine you will have to use a [routable IP address](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40328/what-is-a-routable-ip).

Comment: the server is created on a raspberry pi. does that mean i can only access it from the pi or does it mean i can access it on a computer which is connected to the pi (through wifi?).

Comment: You can certainly access your server from your computer, but you probably will have to use a different IP, i.e. not localhost. [This tutorial](https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-local-web-server--cms-19943) seems like it will be useful to you for setting this up

Comment: I found the following on Quora: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-make-my-localhost-server-website-be-accessible-by-other-computer Would I be able to make it work in this way? Because a routable IP address enables it around the web, but it is important that this system is only accessible locally - LAN.

Comment: This setup will allow you to access on your local network. Anyone with this public IP can access it, but as long as you aren't giving out this IP number no one else would know how to access it.